# Solving system of equations in parallel

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I'm trying to solve a system in parallel. I'm using the example from

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/196655-linear-least-squares-mldivide-for-large-matrices-in-parallel

and I get the error

```
Starting parallel pool (parpool) using the 'local' profile ... Error using parpool (line 103)
Not enough input arguments.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely because your local cluster job storage got corrupted somehow. Find `local_cluster_jobs` folder, delete it, and restart Matlab. On Windows it is probably located at the following path (could slightly differ depending on your Matlab version, though):

```
%AppData%\MathWorks\MATLAB\local_cluster_jobs
```